# Monitor PSU troubleshooting (Monitor sometimes doesn't want to turn on)

Tags: power-supply, capacitor, troubleshooting, monitor

My Packard Bell Viseo 223ws monitor sometimes doesn't power on. I'm guessing that it's a problem with the PSU since it sometimes works flawlessly but other times the power button doesn't even light up.
I have desoldered all the electrolytic capacitors of the PSU PCB (except the big AC filter cap because it's glued on) and measured them. Some 270 uF caps have 260 uF but that was the biggest deviation. I guess they should still be fine.
I'm hoping that somebody has another recommendation on what to check so I can hopefully get it working properly again. The PSU PCB is labeled 491981400100R but I couldn't find a schematic.
It's a 2009 model so I was guessing that the caps might have gone bad but I don't have any other ideas.

Thank you.

[image: PSU]

[image: PSU]

[image: Signal board]

[image: Signal board]

Comment: Low voltage capacitor(s) for the backlight inverter (top part of your second image) or driver are the most common culprit in my experience. No power LED sounds different though. My guess would still be on a capacitor going bad.

Comment: Try replacing the green electro cap near D803

Comment: For an explanation of how a general flyback supply works, Ken Shirrif has a good explanation. www.righto.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Don't test the Caps, replace them.**

You can not reliably tell a cap is good by a simple measurement. Maybe the Capacitor only fails under load, or the parasitic inductivity just increased a lot.

They are so cheap anyways, i would not even bother soldering them back on or testing them.

I had similar problems with my ASUS Monitor, not turning on sometimes, then more often, then it hardly turned on at all. It was solved by just replacing all caps in the power supply area.

If you own a Oscilloscope and know what to do, you can check the signal at the output of the PSU and see how the filtering failed, but be sure to not electrocute yourself.

Such Problems are almost always related to the capacitors, as a failure of a semiconductors or inductors would be aprupt and it would cease to work at all (resistors rarely fail, and when they do, you can see and smell it most of the time).
What happens here is that at power-on the degraded caps are no longer able to stabilize the voltage fast enough, and then the digital parts of the circuit behind it (the controller, or even the integrated circuit of the inverter for the backlight) fail to start up.

Sometimes it still works because you happen to switch it on at exactly the right time regarding the the Sine wave of the AC current, and the ripple at the output of the PSU is just a tad lower at this moment, so it switches on.

Comment: Replacing ALL the capacitors is a bit of a shotgun approach. In some instances it might be valid, but not all.  It is also important to replace capacitors with ones of the correct spécification otherwise with a shotgun approach you end up introducing more problems.

Comment: As a side note, the board in the last picture also has some capacitors on it that might be problematic, especially the ones next to the LDO in the top right corner (the black part there labeled 1084-33 is a Low DropOut regulator to supply the logic part, likely 5V), but i would still guess the problem is with the capacitors on the PSU board, and most likely they are all faulty, or at least several of them. My guess would be the one of the 5 caps in the lower right corner of the PSU PCB, in the low voltage line, but that is just a wild guess. In theory even the big AC filter cap could cause it.

Comment: @Kartman there are 7 relevant capacitors on the PSU board, 5 of which i am quite sure have the same rating. Of course the specifications need to match, not only Voltage, capacitance and thermal rating, but also maybe the ripple-tolerance etc, although that likely does not matter much. Also, care must be taken to not mix up the polarity when replacing.

Comment: My money in on the little green one.

Comment: Thank you all for the suggestions. @Kartman I measured the green cap and it was up to spec but yeah measuring isn't that reliable in this case.

Comment: @Boldar I will replace all electrolytic caps of the logic board and the low voltage side of the PSU since they aren't that expensive and it would be much more effort to assemble and test every time after buying new caps.

Comment: The way to measure the capacitors is to use an ESR meter. The average multimeter is next to useless.

Comment: I don't have an ESR meter. My local electronics supplier doesn't have the 270uF caps in stock so I will try if it works without replaying the two (between the transformers).